# Minyan vs oneg shabbat

Tags: halacha, oneg-shabbat

Suppose if one went to minyan on Friday night, they would get home late after their oven turned off (and they didn’t have a hot plate) and thus all the food would be lukewarm. Would it be better to stay home and daven yourself so that your food can be hot and you can have a proper oneg Shabbat, or would you still say go to shul despite missing out on the oneg. Would the answer be it’s a matter of minyan which is d’rabbanan vs oneg Shabbat which is d’orayta?

Comment: I have the same question about sleeping in Shabbos morning.

Comment: How about eat and then go to shul?

Comment: It's the old pass-off-your-selfishness-as-piety trick, Chief! I've seen it *millions* of times! (So did Shlomo HaMelech. Mishlei Ch. 7:  וְהֶחֱזִיקָה בּוֹ, וְנָשְׁקָה לּוֹ;    הֵעֵזָה פָנֶיהָ, וַתֹּאמַר לוֹ.  זִבְחֵי שְׁלָמִים עָלָי;    הַיּוֹם, שִׁלַּמְתִּי נְדָרָי עַל-כֵּן, יָצָאתִי לִקְרָאתֶךָ;    לְשַׁחֵר פָּנֶיךָ, וָאֶמְצָאֶךָּ. The yetzer hara doesn't just say "you're allowed to do this sin", it says "it's a *mitzvah* to do this sin!")